# How do I extract names with initials in R using sub?

Tags: r, regex

I have several paragraphs that I am trying to extract initials with their correlative name.

For example, I might have a paragraph with lots of text that has the name "A. J. Balfour" in it, or "J. Balfour".

This is what I am writing right now and it doesn't work. I would love your feedback!

```
z = "This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A J Balfour"

sub("^(([A]\\\S+\\\s){1}\\\S+).*", "\\1", z, perl = TRUE)
```

I am thinking the best option is using `sub`, but I am having issues getting my regular expression to work. I am having trouble finding good info on writing a regular expression that will extract characters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stringr` library has the `str_extract` functions with an easier syntax than just using `sub`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(z, "[A]\\S{0,1}\\s(\\S\\S{0,1}\\s){0,1}.*")
#[1] "A J Balfour"
```

**Edit:**
Here is another attempt, but since you are asking for a more general solution, it is very difficult to get an exact match.

```
z<-c( "This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A J Balfour",
      "J Balfour",
      'This is a bunch of text.  G. Balfour'
)

str_extract_all(z, "([A-Z]+[\\. ]{1,2}){1,2}.*")

# (      - start of grouping
# [A-Z]  - Any capital letter
# +      - at least 1 times
# [\\. ]   - a period or a space
# {1,2} - one or two times
#  ){1,2} - 1 or 2 times for the grouping
# .*    - any character zero or more times
```

In fact this attempt fails on the first test.  Narrowing down to [A-J] would help.
Good luck.

Comment: I will use stringr then! Thank you. I am new to regular expressions . . . can I extract all instances of "J Balfour" ?

z = "This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A J Balfour and maybe some other words like J Balfour. Is this possible?"

Comment: I am attempting this now: str_extract_all("This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A. J. Balfour and maybe some other words or another A. Balfour or even G. Balfour", regex("[[A-J]. Balfour]+", TRUE))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I ended up using str_extract_all to look like this:

z = "This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A. J. Balfour and maybe some other words or another A. F. Balfour or even G. G. Balfour or maybe even A. G. Balfour"

str_extract_all(z, regex("[A-Z]. [A-Z]. Balfour", simplify = TRUE))

Thanks for all the thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
  using regmatches in base R.

```
z = "This is a bunch of text. I would like to extract A J Balfour"

regmatches(z,regexpr("[A]\\s{1}\\S+.*", z))
#[1] "A J Balfour"
```